# ELASTIC SEARCH - To boost the query to compare an input list with a document field that is also a list

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

ELASTIC SEARCH - How to get the query boosted when I have to compare an input list with a document field that is also a list.

USE CASE -

In elastic search there are some documents and each document has a list of *applicableCities* associated with it. There is a list of cities as an input.

How to create a query that satisfies the below points.

1. The documents that have exact match (i.e. all *applicableCities* are same as the *inputCities*) should boost the query by a certain factor(lets say X). These documents should come on top once queried.
2. The documents that don't have all the *inputCities* in the *applicableCities* list should boost the query by a certain factor - Y (where X > Y).
3. The documents that have all the *inputCities* in the *applicableCities* list but the count doesn't match. Such scenario should boost the query by a certain factor lets say X' (where X > X' > Y).

Example - 
Input list - ["Thailand", "Bangkok", "Phuket"]

Documents having applicablePlaces as  ["Thailand", "Bangkok", "Phuket"] should come on top and should boost query by X.
Documents having applicablePlaces as  ["Thailand", "Bangkok", "Phuket","Pattaya"] should boost query by X' [ X > X'].
Documents having applicablePlaces as  ["Thailand", "Bangkok"] should boost query by Y (X' > Y).
Documents having applicablePlaces as  ["Bangkok"] should boost query by Z  (Y > Z).
Documents having applicablePlaces as  ["Thailand"] should boost query by Z (Y > Z).

I used term query for each of the city as below but it is incorrect as the boost should be on the entire one rather than each term query.

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "applicableCities": {
              "value": "Phuket",
              "boost": 20
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "applicableCities": {
              "value": "Bangkok",
              "boost": 20
            }
          }
        },
{
          "term": {
            "applicableCities": {
              "value": "Thailand",
              "boost": 20
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Below termSQuery is also incorrect as it used OR as on operator

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "packageCities": [
              "Pattaya",
              "Bangkok"
            ],
            "boost": 20
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Nested Query with Must for Multiple values check with AND ?   "must": [
  {
    "nested": {
      "path": "fieldName",
      "query": {
        "term": {
         
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "nested": {
      "path": "fieldName",
      "query": {
        "term": {
        
        }
      }
    }
  }]

Comment: @KC fragnace - Thanks for your input though I already have tried that but it wont help.

The use case is that elastic should return the docs even if it doesnt match perfecty.

Now the boosting should be dont on basis of how well both the lists match.

Say the input list is ["a","b"] that I will put in query.

Elastic docs present are -
doc1 - ["a","b","c"], doc2 - ["a","b"], doc3 - ["a","b",c","d"], doc4 - ["e","f"]

The output sequence should be - 
doc2, doc1, doc3, doc4